# redirect_uri_mismatch while trying to authenticate with Google API

Tags: ios, google-api

I have a tricky problem. I have a need to start a Google Authentication using an iOS app and hand off the `code` value that Google API returns to a server end point that I created. This works perfectly fine if I was initiating the request from a `JavaScript` application. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) the Google Documentation.

However, if I initate the request from the iOS app using the following code, it comes back and say I have a URI Mismatch because the oAuth ID I created if a `Web Application` type. If I use `Other`, I'll get another error, which is `Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Invalid code.'.`

Having said that, here is how I'm initiating the auth from the iOS app.

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
NSURL *tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
// the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
// loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page.
NSString *redirectURI = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"Google"
                                                                                  tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                                               redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                                                  clientID:kClientID
                                                                              clientSecret:kClientSecret];
```

Do you see any glaring issues?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect url must be registered into the google cloud app. It cannot use wildcards.

I would say: make sure that it is getting the proper redirect uri. It is paramount that the uri is precise.

Comment: Alberto, thanks, but the `redirectURI` here is arbitrary value for iOS app. That's at least what the document says.

If you do not think so, what should be the `redirect_uri`? Is it the fully qualified path to my server API?

Comment: the redirectURI shoud be a fully qualified parth to a folder or file in your server.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being using the Google Sign-In as a way to authenticate a user: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Comment: I'm using that exactly and still getting redirect_uri_mismatch. I'm able to verify the token using the verify_oauth2_token function but can't do the credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code